# Execute php url from jscript

Tags: javascript, php, url

So atm I have this which does work. Basicaly I want to execute the sendTo php file without changing to the new page. The location will cause my page to go to the php one and I don't want this. From the php page I can redirect it back to the original page, but I don't really like to do that. This is just some code added to an old app, it does not need to be pretty, it needs to work.

```
function showVal(newVal, taskid){
    var sendTo = "update_event.php?id_task=" + taskid + "&done=" + newVal;
    document.location.href = sendTo;
}
```

Comment: have you consider to use jquery?, query can offer you a solution for that kind of matter, just use .ajax

Comment: its not worth my time to do that. I just need to add that functionality and leave. I can also see what do I have in the php file and write it directly in the jscript. But like I said, I need a quick fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery for this, what you need to do is perform an ajax request.

First include jQuery in your page: 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Then in your javascript you can do something like this:

```
function showVal(newVal, taskid) {
   $.get('update_event.php', { id_task: taskid, done: newVal}, 
       function(returnedData){
            console.log(returnedData);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ok, since you need a quick fix, i assume importing jquery wont be a whole deal this would be an example using ajax...

```
   function showVal(newVal, taskid){
    $.ajax({url: "update_event.php?id_task=" + taskid + "&done=" + newVal;, success: function(result){
        //here you can do things with the return result, for example, if you want to display it inside a div
            $("#div1").html(result);
        //or if you just want to alert it 
            alert(result);

        // if you dont want to do anithing, just leave the result in blank.

    }});
```

if you dont want to download jquery, you can just link it with this link

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty from the dark ages of web development, just hide a blank iFrame somewhere in the page, and go like this:

```
function showVal(newVal, taskid){
    var sendTo = "update_event.php?id_task=" + taskid + "&done=" + newVal;
    document.getElementById('yourhiddenframe').src = sendTo;
}
```

If you need to check for execution, look into **onLoad** for the iFrame.

Comment: i would not recomend it, but i give you +1 since it answers exactly the question.